How to pass a Selenium WebElement to Generic 'Action' Methods through Cucumber Steps?
I have created generic methods to perform common actions using Selenium such as 'click' and to find whether an element is present on a page or not. These methods are mapped to a Cucumber step and the element on which the action or validation has to be performed is passed as a parameter.
However, this is where things get a little messy - the type of the parameter is a String, so the generic method gets the parameter, and then calls a method using a generic page object (that is instantiated to the current page at runtime) with the same parameter - this page object method consists of a switch case that maps the string to the matching WebElement and returns the WebElement to the calling generic function, which then performs the required action or validation.
Having these generic method makes it easy as there is only one step to use across all feature files and any change in the behaviour needs to be implemented in only one place. However, I find the whole switch case shenanigans to be quite an inelegant way of handling this.
Is there a better way of doing all this?
